# Javascript match if variable has more than five zeros

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to check if src has more than five consecutive zeros. For example http://domain.com/images/00000007.jpg would match but http://domain.com/images/0000_1.jpg wouldn't. This is what I have so far but it doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

```
if (src.match(/0{5,}$/)) {
  match found
}
else {
  no match found
}
```

Comment: the `$` anchors your regular expression to the end of the string.  Is that what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>You should match zeros from the beginning `^` of the string, i.e.</s>

```
if (/^0{5,}/.test(src)) { ... }
```

If you need to match 5 consecutive zeros at any place of the string, then omit any `^` or `$`.

**UPDATED:** In your case you can use something like `if (/\/0{5,}/.test(src)) { ... }`.

Comment: Should he?  He only said "Has more than 5 consecutive zeros" - not "Starts with" - I'm thinking `/0{5}/`should work just fine...

Comment: Ah because the `src` is a full path not just the file name, maybe `/\/0{5,}/` ?

Comment: I revised the question. the src variable will have a full url. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @JasonSperske Exactly what I was thinking about `;)`

Comment: @Tony, `/0{5}/` will match five zeros anywhere in the string - are sources like `http://site.com/00000/1.jpg` supposed to match?  What about `http://site.com/folder/image_0000000002.gif`?

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative you could also use [**indexOf()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), similar to this:

```
if(src.indexOf('00000') > -1){
    alert('matchFound');
} else {
    alert('no match found');
}
```

Comment: +1 as indexOf is much faster that a regular expression (though not noticeably here).

Comment: @RobG: I didn't know that. Very interesting. I added `indexOf()` as an alternative based on the original post's title `match if variable has more than five zeros` as it seemed a simple enough evaluation. OP then added the example Urls. In that case I assume a regular expression would be required if the `000000` must follow a `/` in the string and exclude folder names or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on for size:

```
/0{5,}[^\/]*$/
```

It checks for five or more zeros, followed by anything but forward slashes to the end of the string.  If you want to do other validation, you can start the pattern  with a forward slash to ensure the file starts with five zeros, or you can add acceptable filetypes at the end:

```
/\/0{5,}[^\/]*\.(jpe?g|gif|png)$/i
```

A breakdown(for any parts you or future readers don't know):

```
/             Starts the regular expression
  \/          A literal forward slash (escaped because '/' is a delimiter)
  0{5,}       Five or more zeros
  [^\/]*      Anything except a literal forward slash, zero or more times.
  \.          A literal period (unescaped periods match anything except newlines)
  (           start a group
    jpe?g     jpeg or jpg (the ? makes the 'e' match zero or 1 times)
    |         OR
    gif       gif
    |         OR
    png       png
  )           End group
  $           Assert the end of the string.
/             End the regular expression
i             Case insensitive.
```